# Dlink DSL-2730u stuck on firmware update now showing red on power led

Tags: modem, firmware, dsl-modem

While trying to update firmware dlink DSL-2730u stucked and now power led turns red. No response from modem and can't access modem page 192.168.1.1 even after setting default gateway. Lan led blinking while connecting. How to resolve this?

Comment: Was the firmware you installed a custom third party firmware, or was it from Dlink?

Comment: it was dlink firmware